# Access to TCP statistics/information per socket possible? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I require some informations like the amount of resend packages/packet-loss occurred for a specific TCP-Socket I created. Does somebody know a way how to access or request such informations directly from my C/C++ program? Maybe something Linux specific?

Or do I need (as a workaround) to capture and analyze my own traffic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using `getsockopt()` to get or `setsockopt()` to set TCP socket options, you can use `TCP_INFO` option on linux machines in order to get information about a socket. This option should be avoided if you want the code to be portable.

What you will get back is a [struct tcp_info](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~dclark/am_256_graph_theory/linux_2_6_stack/structtcp__info.html) from the kernel that contains information such as retransmissions, lost packets, states etc.

Comment: Sadly this isn't easy to find and tcp_info seems to be not very well documented. However, after some trial & error it seems to deliver what I need. Thanks!

Comment: There's a write-up here: https://linuxgazette.net/136/pfeiffer.html "The first part consists of administrative information such as state, retransmits, keepalive probes, and options. There's more, and I went through the Linux kernel code to discover where the values come from and what they mean. The best documentation you can get is to look at your kernel's source at .../net/ipv4/tcp.c and see how the tcp_info is filled. Look for the tcp_get_info() function inside, and look up the definition of struct tcp_sock in .../include/net/tcp.h. Most of the data is copied from this structure."