# Ruby TCP Server - can I get how many times a TCP packet has retried?

Tags: ruby, tcp, tcpserver

I am running a Ruby TCP server (https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPServer.html) to accept packets from sensor modems on a fixed TCP port. I wondered if I can get the number of retries the packet has taken to get a successful round trip? There doesn't seem to be this information in the TCP header - https://networklessons.com/cisco/ccie-routing-switching-written/tcp-header.

I cannot see any info in the parent classes either: TCPServer -> TCPSocket.

I am trying to debug lost packets from the modem when it uses UDP, so I thought TCP might be a good method as I believe it retries if the ack times out. If I can measure the retries with TCP it might go some way to explain the lost packets on UDP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use `ping` to test the connection? Btw. UDP packets can get lost for numerous different reasons. Never use it if you want reliable transmission without some sort of packet ACK mechanism. I suppose you know this already, but it is rather strange to expect UDP to not lose packets.

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842118/counting-tcp-retransmissions

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203553/access-to-tcp-statistics-information-per-socket-possible-c-c